# Search engine friendly html meta tag needed

Tags: html

My Six month old Website is not listed in google page rank well. Is there any modification required?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="description" content="<?php echo $page_description; ?>" />

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >
<meta name="keywords" content=" site key words" >
<meta name="classification" content="site classification" >
<meta name="rating" content="general" >
<meta name="distribution" content="global" >
<meta name="author" content="site author" >

</head>
```

Comment: That just means your website isn't as viewed as any of the other sites

Comment: meta tag is correct?

Comment: If you added enugh keywords, then yeah

Comment: Google SEO members state that meta tags are more or less ignored by search engines these days. The go for content, that is original content, not copied content. And they like changes in content.

Comment: @Bálint <meta name="" content=" " >   and   <meta name="" content=" " /> both are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Primarily, its the content that is key. Its kind of chicken and egg - you need engaged visitors in order to rank well, and your visitors won't come unless they find you in google. Concentrate on the content and the marketing. Other than ensuring that the description is attractive and likely to tempt people in, its not about meta tags.

If you really want to work on the meta information, think about open graph and promoting socially. The two go hand in hand.

Comment: <meta name="" content=" " > and <meta name="" content=" " /> both are correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a modification, but you have just tipped the iceberg. There is a long way to go.

What you are after is probably SEO. Short for Search Engine Optimization. Easy said: getting ranked better in the Search Engine Result Pages (SERP). There are a ton of courses to follow to get you ranked better. The best thing to do is to add value to your readers. Creating content, marketing it and getting quality backlinks from websites with a high authority. You might want to start here: https://moz.com/learn/seo

Other then that, there might be a problem with the website itself. Does it have a penalty? You can check that and other things through [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/).